# Getting two divs to align side by side

Tags: html

I am trying to get the two divs in the following code to align side by side together, I have put borders on so you can see the div boundaries. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="picturecontainer1" >
<img alt="logo" height="132" src="images/ClevelandLogo.gif" width="126">
</div>
<div id="picturecontainer2">
<img alt="" height="132" src="da.png" width="1000" class="auto-style13">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: float left, float right, you got your answer...

Comment: Where are the borders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/butani_vijay010/DYtzA/)

Code :

```
<div id="picturecontainer1" >
<img alt="logo" height="132" src="images/ClevelandLogo.gif" width="126">
</div>
<div id="picturecontainer2">
<img alt="" height="132" src="da.png" width="1000" class="auto-style13">
</div>
```

css:

```
 div{
display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css:

```
#picturecontainer1{
    float: left;
}
```

This way your `picturecontainer1` is floating so your `picturecontainer2` will align add the side of your `picturecontainer1` if the space is wide enough, otherwise it will go beneath the div.

Jsfidde:

http://jsfiddle.net/uAK4Q/1/